# Why modal in FlatList item does not display in full screen(IOS only)?

Tags: react-native, flatlist, react-native-modal

I'm trying to build app using react-native. I'm using `Flatlist` to display items. When user clicks on more options(dots), Dropdown appears. When user click on any dropdown item Popup is displayed in fullscreen. It works fine in Android but in IOS it appears inside flatlist item.[image: IOS Modal][image: Require modal]

Is there any way to fix this? I have also tried `react-native-modal` , and it behave same.